# Racket: given the seller name, print the result of the products sold in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, racket

the goal of the code is when i type the name of the seller the output must be the quantity of the product sold

```
(define-struct node (seller_info left_tree right_tree))

(define-struct seller (name quantity_sold))

(define treeSellers (make-node (make-seller "laura" 8)
                                   (make-node (make-seller "pedro" 5)empty empty)
                                   (make-node (make-seller "laura" 10)empty empty)
  )
 )
  
(define (addTree sellerName tree)
(cond
  [(empty? tree) empty]
  [(string=? sellerName (seller-name (node-seller_info tree)))
   (+ (seller-quantity_sold (node-seller_info tree)))]
  [else (addTree sellerName (node-left_tree tree))
        (addTree sellerName (node-right_tree tree))]
  )
  )
```

the output must be

`(addTree "laura" treeSellers) 18`

but is instead

`(addTree "laura" treeSellers) 8`

Any suggestions to cause the output to go the wanted one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main problems with your code:

- The base case is wrong, you can't return `empty`, the answer is supposed to be a number, not a list. You must return zero here.
- Once you find a match, you stopped the recursion - but there could be more matches, you have to keep looking.
- In the `else` case, you're not adding together both results, in effect, you discard the value of the left subtree and only return the value of the right subtree.

This should fix all the issues:

```
(define (addTree sellerName tree)
  (cond
    [(empty? tree) 0]
    [(string=? sellerName (seller-name (node-seller_info tree)))
     (+ (seller-quantity_sold (node-seller_info tree))
        (addTree sellerName (node-left_tree tree))
        (addTree sellerName (node-right_tree tree)))]
    [else
     (+ (addTree sellerName (node-left_tree tree))
        (addTree sellerName (node-right_tree tree)))]))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(addTree "laura" treeSellers)
=> 18
(addTree "pedro" treeSellers)
=> 5
(addTree "ivan" treeSellers)
=> 0
```

Comment: wow thank you so much im a begginer at this thats why so many problems